Windows 10 can't open external HDD with Ubuntu
I'll be as simple as I can.
I had an old pc with ubuntu in a simple HDD.
This pc in 2 year was used but with Ubuntu was a little hard for the elderly woman that was using it.
I removed the HDD (with ubuntu on), and I installed another SSD (with Windows 10).
Now the "new" computer will not visualize any disk if I connect the old HDD with an external reader.
I need to recover some folders.
What is the SAFEST and fastest way to:
-Enter this HDD and recover this files
-Without Paying nor deleting anything
P.S.: If I remove the new SSD and put back the old HDD with ubuntu the pc will start with ubuntu again.
Sorry if I mispelled something but I'm trying my best.
P.P.S: The HDD is in perfect form and it's working like always.

Boot a Ubuntu live system and explore what file-systems exist on the machine, chances are they're not a file-system that is native to a windows machine which is why you cannot mount it on a windows system, but we're not windows support, so asking what you need to modify on a windows system to make it read foreign file-systems isn't on-topic for this Ubuntu site.  We can help you read it if using a Ubuntu live system (which you'd use to copy to another file-system that windows can use).  You provided no specifics on Ubuntu system, so we can't yet guess what fs maybe there.

If you have access to a system running Ubuntu (or any Linux distro probably) - connect it to that, it’ll be the easiest option. It’s almost certainly Ext3 / Ext4 which Windows can’t cope with. If you don’t have a Linux computer available, use a live USB session to access the drive. You might need 3 drives - the source drive, the live usb session drive, and another place to put the data that is fat / ntfs so windows can access it.

This question is similar to: How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?). If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Follow the instructions in the accepted answer of the linked duplicate question for chroot-ing into the Ubuntu that is installed on the HDD from an Ubuntu live USB. Change the boot priority in the BIOS to boot the USB 1st

Use total commander: https://www.ghisler.com/ and its plugin for Linux file systems: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext4tc/files/ext4Plugin/ext4Plugin-0.17/ext4Plugin_64.zip/download
